# Get original Image from flattened tensor/numpy array

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In a Convolution Neural Network can we get the original image matrix (i.e. the input layer) from the first flattened layer? According to my primary understanding, it is not possible to get back the image but is there any way we could?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an input through a neural network, and retain the activations in some later layer of the network, it generally won't be possible to use those activations alone to recover the input. That is, for some input `X`, and the function `f` that maps the input to the activity in the later layer, `f` is typically not invertible. For an ordinary convolutional neural network, `f` would be the composition of convolutions, pooling operations, non-linear activation functions, and matrix multiplications.

Procedures exist that can recover an input `X'` for which `f(X')` is close to `f(X)`.

[Feature Visualization](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/) on distill.pub covers relevant techniques.